# What to change all my references to localhost to after deploying a Spring Boot and React App using Heroku

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, package.json

I have just deployed my application which uses Spring Boot and React on the front end. The Heroku app is working, I can see the page that is suppose to display, and when I make a `GET` request I get the proper response. But the frontend is not really communicating with the backend like it did when I run both locally. For example, on the front page you should be able to click a button and that sends a `POST` request to the server.

I am pretty sure I know the *only* reason for this issue but I do not know how to fix it. There are two spots in the client and one line in the server where I reference `https://localhost:8080/request`, or some other localhost url. Here are the associated areas in my code.

Client:

```
await (await fetch('http://localhost:8080/decide', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })).json();
```

In my package.json:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
```

On the backend:

```
@RestController
public class DecideController {

  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
  @RequestMapping(value="/decide", method= RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<SimpleNode> decide(@RequestBody Decide decide) {
    SimpleNode currentNode = decide.getNode();
    return new ResponseEntity<SimpleNode>(currentNode, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

I am just not sure what to replace these references to `localhost` with. I was thinking I could put the Heroku app's URL there, but then I am not sure what port to use for the client/server or if it would be the same for both. I have struggled to find a decent explanation of what to put there.

Hopefully these instances where I use `localhost` really is the *only* issue with it. If you need any more information or clarification let me know.

Comment: Either use .env files or make a config file where the values differ per environment. Then use the vars where you make the calls and check cross origin

Comment: Have you deployed your react app with `http://localhost:8080/decide` same end point?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. They are both a part of the executable jar file which I used to deploy. When I run the executable jar locally, it works fine.